# JavaMail MimeMessage.getContent unsupported encoding

Tags: email, encoding, jakarta-mail

I´m having a problem with parsing some type of mail encoding with charset=t.101-g2

I´m using JavaMail in Grails directly using the lib, getting the unread emails from IMAP, and for each message try to get the content with
Object msgContent = msg.getContent()

And that line is throwing the error.

The exception

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: t.101-g2 [See nested exception: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: t.101-g2
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:100)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:107)
    at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:790)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:537)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1453)
```

The mail is like :

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
From: "Some Email" <some_email@some.com>
Content-type: text/plain; charset=t.101-g2
Subject: SomeSubject
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 06:55:36 -0500
X-Source: /usr/local/cpanel/bin/autorespond
X-Source-Args: /usr/local/cpanel/bin/autorespond some_email@some.com /home/oriental/.autorespond 
X-Source-Dir: /home/oriental

Some Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JavaMail FAQ entry should help:

- [Why do I get the UnsupportedEncodingException when I invoke getContent() on a bodypart that contains text data?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#unsupen)